# Not being able to create wave file through mciSendString

Tags: c#, skype4com, mcisendstring

I am trying capture a skype call and save it in my PC with a wave extension, but every time I am trying the `mciSendString` it fails to create sound file.

Here is my code

```
public void Skype_CallStatus(Call call, TCallStatus status)
{
    int result = 0;
     Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Windows.Forms.Application.ExecutablePath);
    if (status == TCallStatus.clsInProgress)
    {
        mciSendString("open new Type waveaudio Alias recsound", "", 0, 0);
        mciSendString("record recsound", "", 0, 0);

    }
    //else if (status == TCallStatus.clsFinished)
    else if (status == TCallStatus.clsFinished)
    {
        DateTime currdate = DateTime.Now;
        //string datetime = currdate.Day + currdate.Month + currdate.Year + "_" + currdate.Hour + currdate.Minute + currdate.Second;
        string datetime = string.Format("{0:yyyyMMddhhmmss}.wav", DateTime.Now);

        string wavfilename = "";
        if (config.AppSettings.Settings["VoiceRecordsPath"].Value != null)
        {
            //wavfilename = config.AppSettings.Settings["VoiceRecordsPath"].Value.Replace(",","") + "_" + CSRBusiness.User.Country + "_" + datetime + @".wav";
            wavfilename = CSRBusiness.User.Country + "_" + datetime;
        }
        Directory.SetCurrentDirectory(config.AppSettings.Settings["VoiceRecordsPath"].Value.Replace(",", ""));

        result = mciSendString("save recsound " + wavfilename, "", 0, 0);
        //result = mciSendString("save recsound d://test.wav", "", 0, 0);
        mciSendString("close recsound ", "", 0, 0);
        MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
    }
   // MessageBox.Show(result.ToString());
}
```

The path is where I need to save the file:

```
C:\\Users\\tridip.BBAKOLKATA\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\CSRAssistant\\CSRAssistant\\bin\\Debug\\VoiceRecords
```

What kind of mistake is there is in my code?

But when I hard code the path and file name in `mciSendString` like `result = mciSendString("save recsound d://test.wav", "", 0, 0);` then a file was created but the skype call was not recorded when I played that wave file.

What is wrong in my path specification?

A second thing is that when the wave file was generated, the voice was not recorded. Why?

Answer (score 2):

The API call may fail if the path or file name in the command string has embedded spaces. Therefore include the path in double quotes:

```
result = mciSendString("save recsound \"" + wavfilename + "\"", "", 0, 0);
```

or, starting with C# 6.0:

```
result = mciSendString($"save recsound \"{wavfilename}\"", "", 0, 0);
```

See KB191089 [PRB: Multimedia API Calls May Fail with Long File Names](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/191089)

Comment: ok will try. can u tell me why mciSendString not being able to capture skype conversation. it just capture my voice but what other people is saying from another end that is not being capture.

Comment: if the path would be long then mciSendString will fail?

Comment: Not if you include it in quotes as I have shown in my code example. The Problem is probably not the length but the embedded spaces. (Long filenames have often embedded spaces).

Answer (score 1):

before calling "save recsound" you should create the folder "VoiceRecords" at the desired path.